# Lock tables and/or transaction for stock table?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, locking, innodb

How can I maintain data integrity for a stock table with InnoDB? Does this require the use of both a table lock and a transaction? I have tried to find some good examples, but even well known opensource ecommerce software doesn't implement table locks/transactions. Would below code work? Do I really need to lock the whole table, or is there a way to only lock the rows of the sold products? Or does anyone have a good example?

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
    `product_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `quantity` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

.

```
LOCK TABLES stock WRITE;
START TRANSACTION;
SET autocommit = 0;
UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity - 4 WHERE product_id = 'PRODUCT_1' AND quantity >= 4;
UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity - 2 WHERE product_id = 'PRODUCT_2' AND quantity >= 2;
UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity - 5 WHERE product_id = 'PRODUCT_3' AND quantity >= 5;
COMMIT or ROLLBACK;
```

COMMIT if all UPDATE queries have 1 affected row, otherwise ROLLBACK

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to do the table-lock, unless you want to make sure concurrent clients running the same code don't run simultaneous updates. I'm not sure that matters, because each of your updates is working on distinct subsets of rows.

In any case, it's not necessary to set autocommit=0 after you start a transaction. Starting a transaction implicitly means that it won't commit until you use COMMIT (or some statement causes an implicit commit).

You might even wrap all three updates into one update, except that you said you want to make sure each update changes at least one row.

Answer (score 0):

"1 affected row" is not what is tested.  Failure, deadlock, timeout, etc are tested.  If you want to fail if it is not exactly 1 row each, then you need to fetch rows_affected, test it for "1", then `ROLLBACK` or not.

Also, the

```
COMMIT or ROLLBACK
```

needs to be "if ... then ROLLBACK else COMMIT".  This is best done in your application language.